# Installing Docker on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, docker

My morning so far has been banging my head against trying to get the docker installation to work, so far I have had no luck. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server set up. I know there are a few articles on this set up but none of them seem to help out.

The guide I have been following: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Here is the steps of what happens.

First:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

[image]

Which is good! The next step is a sudo apt-get update which returns something less good. A lot of documentation I have read does not seem to help me solve this, so I plug on to see if something will correct this later. 
[image]
Third step is

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

No issues here.

Fourth step is the docker fingerprint key

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Which just outputs OK

Fifth step I do is the `sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88` which outputs the key as it is shown in the docker installation documentation.

Sixth step is the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
```

No output is shown just brings me to a new command line.

Seventh step is `sudo apt-get update` which shows the same output as in step 2.

Eigth step is the actual install. s`udo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`
Which outputs:
[image]

I am not sure of what files to edit. But every line is spelled correctly and it still throws issues my way and I am at a loss. If anyone has any tips thatd be fantastic.

Comment: Step 1: "10 not upgraded." Fix that first by running an apt full-upgrade.

Comment: There has to be a typo in the repo URL you originally had. See how it says `/linux/ubunutu` in the URL that returns 404 in `sudo apt update`? Find the corresponding file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`s (or `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly) and fix this line.

Comment: Currently working on the full-upgrade at the moment.
I will check the repo url when that is done, I am just now noticing that since you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is your host's CPU arch `64-bit`?

I had the same issues trying to install `docker` on `32-bit Ubuntu 18.04`. On `32-bit` hosts, you need to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989534/how-to-install-docker-on-32bit-machine-having-ubuntu-12-04/48881019#48881019).